# BigQuery LEFT OUT JOIN error for a temp function?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table I have create in BigQuery.

In that table I have some placeholder values in fields.

I then thought I could simply update the placeholder values, so I wrote a small temp function

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getBoroughFromCoords(longitude FLOAT64, latitude FLOAT64 )
    RETURNS STRING 
    AS ((SELECT CAST(UPPER(tz_loc.borough)as STRING) FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` tz_loc WHERE (ST_DWithin(tz_loc.zone_geom, ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude),0)) )
);
```

and tested it like this `sql select getBoroughFromCoords(-73.95908, 40.705246)` and it returned "BROOKLYN" - which was great.

But when I try to update a value (and I am specifially targetting a single row here for testing) using:

```sql
UPDATE `project-id.datasetid.collated_data` 
SET NEIGHBORHOOD = (select getBoroughFromCoords(LONG, LAT))
WHERE collision_date = "2019-10-27" AND LAT = 40.705246 AND LONG = -73.95908
```

I get the error "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

What I don't understand is why? I mean, this function is standalone, correct? it just takes in 2 params and returns a string, so why does it suddenly want a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encounter the LEFT OUTER JOIN error since you are not passing values to LONG and LAT on your subquery. To fix this you should SET values to these variables at the start of your query.

```
DECLARE long_var, lat_var  FLOAT64;
SET long_var = -73.95908;
SET lat_var = 40.705246;
```

To test this out, I just created a table with dummy values just enough to satisfy your WHERE conditions.

[image]

Query used:

```
DECLARE long_var, lat_var  FLOAT64;
SET long_var = -73.95908;
SET lat_var = 40.705246;

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getBoroughFromCoords(longitude FLOAT64, latitude FLOAT64 )
    RETURNS STRING 
    AS ((SELECT CAST(UPPER(tz_loc.borough)as STRING) FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` tz_loc 
    WHERE (ST_DWithin(tz_loc.zone_geom, ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude),0)))
);

UPDATE `project-id.dataset_id.collated_data` 
SET NEIGHBORHOOD = (select getBoroughFromCoords(long_var, lat_var))
WHERE collision_date = "2019-10-27" AND LAT = lat_var AND LONG = long_var
```

Output:

[image]

Query `project-id.dataset_id.collated_data` table:

[image]

Comment: The answer is exactly right - thought I could use that to help me, but I can't :( but it doesn't stop the anwer being correct